# How to use a trait several times in a class?

Tags: php, traits

The following code:

```php
trait T {
    function foo() {}
}

class C {
    use T { T::foo as bar; }
    use T { T::foo as baz; }
}
```

Produces the following error:

> Trait method bar has not been applied, because there are collisions
>   with other trait methods on C

Is it possible to use a trait twice in a class?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

To "import" a method defined in a trait multiple times with different names do this:

```
class C {
  use T {
    foo as bar;
    foo as baz;
  }
}
```

Comment: I can see where the question comes from, but with this solution you just have 2 functions with exactly the same functionality, working with exactly the same internals. Why would you want 2 functions that do exactly the same? It would be cool if the "bar" function would use different class attributes than the "baz" function (so that bar and baz actually do the same, but twice), but that is not the case?

Comment: I think this was mostly a theoretical question, hence the very simple answer.

Comment: I've actually needed to do this at least once in my life. In this scenario, it was a parent class that was using the trait twice, where all of the functions took certain parameters, but they meant different things in different contexts. The child class could override one of the two contexts without affecting the other.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use a trait twice:

```
trait T {
    function foo() {}
}

class C {
    use T { T::foo as bar; T::foo as baz; }
}
```