# How to make a variable private to a trait?

Tags: php, oop, traits

I'd like to reuse a functionality several times in a single class. This functionality relies on a private variable:

```php
trait Address {
    private $address;

    public function getAddress() {
        return $this->address;
    }

    public function setAddress($address) {
        $this->address = $address;
    }
}
```

The only way I've found to [use the trait twice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582061/how-to-use-a-trait-several-times-in-a-class), is the following:

```php
class User  {
    use Address {
        getAddress as getHomeAddress;
        setAddress as setHomeAddress;

        getAddress as getWorkAddress;            
        setAddress as setWorkAddress;
    }
}
```

The problem is, by doing this, the private variable `$address` is shared across the different methods, and the code will not work as expected:

```php
$user = new User();
$user->setHomeAddress('21 Jump Street');
echo $user->getWorkAddress(); // 21 Jump Street
```

Is there a solution to really use the trait twice, while not sharing its private variables?

Comment: **A PHP `trait` can currently have nothing private from it's `use` caller** (expander), because PHP is not a compiled-language (i.e. PHP saves a lot of time, by simply imagining that anything in `trait` was written where expanded, same as C++ Macros (though C++ is compiled, and they could make Macro better than Trait)).

Comment: You need to look on the trait as on the code snippet, that is glued into the class. Nothing less, nothing more. It can only save writing same functionality again, just  without the inheritance.

Comment: That's one very ugly example of trait usage. This is not what traits are intended for, there isnt even a benefit from doing this. Just use composition or inheritance. Use a service if you dare and add validation, filters and things. Do not use traits to spawn mutliple private properties. That is awful for anyone else searching occurences and usage and maintaining the code. Just my 2 cents.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Declaring a trait with `use` will not create an instance of that trait. Traits are basically just code that is copy and pasted into the using class. The `as` will only create an Alias for that method, e.g. it will add something like

```
public function getHomeAddress()
{
    return $this->getAddress();
}
```

to your User class. But it will still only be that one trait. There will not be two different `$address` properties, but just one.

You could make the methods private and then delegate any public calls to it via `__call` by switch/casing on the method name and using an array for address, e.g.

```
trait Address {
    private $address = array();

    private function getAddress($type) {
        return $this->address[$type];
    }

    private function setAddress($type, $address) {
        $this->address[$type] = $address;
    }

    public function __call($method, $args) {
        switch ($method) {
            case 'setHomeAddress':
                return $this->setAddress('home', $args[0]);
            // more cases …
        }
    }
}
```

But that is just a can of worms.

In other words, you cannot sanely do what you are trying to do with traits. Either use two different traits. Or use good old aggregation and add concrete proxy methods.

Comment: Although I understand that traits are not *instantiated*, I was still expecting their private variables not to be visible to the class using them, thus potentially allowing to use them several times in a single class, with aliased method names. Looks like I was wrong, so thanks for your answer!

Comment: @Benjamin every class using that trait will have its own instance of the `$address` variable, but it will obviously be visible to the class using it, 'cause traits simply add some behaviour to classes.

Comment: @Matteo Yes, that's becoming a little clearer in my head... This is different from multiple inheritance, because with inheritance the variable would be visible only in the superclass, where here the private variable from the trait is simply "copied" to the actual class.

Comment: This solution seems pretty terrible. Traits are not meant to replace objects - Just get an object address (POPO) if you need one ...

Comment: @Ven that's why the answer says it's a can of worms.

Answer (score 3):

i may be a little late for the party, but the behavior you are trying to create is not something that should be covered by a trait, but by simple object composition.

```
<?php
class Adddress {
    private $street;
    private $number;
    public function __construct(string $street, ?string $number) {}
    public function street() : string {}
    public function number() : string {}
}
class User {
    private $homeAddress;
    private $workAddress;
    public function getHomeAddress() : Address {}
    public function setHomeAddress(Address $homeAddress) : self {}
    public function getWorkAddress() : Address {}
    public function setWorkAddress(Address $workAddress) : self {}
}
```

Comment: This defeats the purpose of having a trait.

Comment: Traits defeat themselves. It's just an OOP way of writing PHP3 style code.

Answer (score 2):

I confirmed that you can alias the same function multiple times, which was a surprise to me.  Although ZendStudio appears to only 'code assist' on the last alias of the function.

Being able to alias the same function multiple times could lend itself to some interesting behavior if the Trait function can determine what name it was called as.  But it does not appear that we can determined the 'aliased' function within a trait function.

Here's my test code:

```
<?php
trait TestTrait
{
    public function test() { print __CLASS__ . ', ' . __TRAIT__ . ', ' . __METHOD__ . ', ' . __FUNCTION__  . "\n"; }
}
class TestClass
{
    use TestTrait { test as test1; test as test2; }
}
$c = new TestClass();
$c->test1();
$c->test2();
```

Output:

```
TestClass, TestTrait, TestTrait::test, test
TestClass, TestTrait, TestTrait::test, test
```

Perhaps it would be nice to add a new `__ALIAS__` constant for trait functions to determine what alias they were called as.

In fact I have created PHP feature request for this:

https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63629

Answer (score 2):

Some years down the line, I followed up on a comment in [bug 63629](https://bugs.php.net/bug.php?id=63629) and produced the following:

```php
<?php
trait TestTrait
{
    private $addresses = [];
    public function getAddress() {
        $calledAs = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1)[0]['function'];
        return $this->addresses[substr($calledAs, 3)];
    }

    public function setAddress($address) {
        $calledAs = debug_backtrace(DEBUG_BACKTRACE_IGNORE_ARGS, 1)[0]['function'];
        $this->addresses[substr($calledAs, 3)] = $address;
    }
}
class TestClass
{
    use TestTrait { getAddress as getHomeAddress; setAddress as setHomeAddress; }
    use TestTrait { getAddress as getWorkAddress; setAddress as setWorkAddress; }
}
$c = new TestClass();

$c->setHomeAddress("High Street, Luton");
echo $c->getHomeAddress();
echo "\n";
$c->setWorkAddress("Business Name, London");
echo $c->getWorkAddress();
echo "\n";
```

which outputs

```
High Street, Luton
Business Name, London
```

It can be done! (With thanks to Dave Farrell whose answer inspired this one.) The arguments to [debug_backtrace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.debug-backtrace.php) are an attempt to minimize memory usage, I'm not certain how much of an effect on performance that is.

Comment: Interesting approach, although your code above has many flaws. It only works because you're doing set, get, set, get. Try to call `setHomeAddress()` then `setWorkAddress()`, now `getHomeAddress()` will return the work address. The reasons are: 1/ you're using `'$calledAs'` (a plain string) instead of `$calledAs` (a variable) and 2/ `$calledAs` contains `getX` or `setX` depending on the method; so the setter writes for example to the array key `setHomeAddress`, while the getter attempts to read from `getHomeAddress`; some normalization is necessary here so that both methods use the same key.

Comment: I'll upvote your answer if you fix these issues, for now I have to downvote it to avoid misleading readers ;-)

Comment: @Benjamin *\*facepalms\** looks like I wasn't paying attention when I wrote that then! Thanks for having a read of that so quickly nearly seven years after your post. Fixed now ;)

Comment: Works perfect now, upvote well deserved! The only caveat is that the method aliases must be named `getX()` / `setX()` (`updateX()` would fail); maybe a check that the method actually starts with `set` and `get` respectively, and an exception otherwise, would make the code safer. Oh, and obviously, the part after `get`/`set` must exactly match (case sensitive typos beware!) - some lowercasing could help, though you can't detect mismatches in method names. All in all, use with caution, but it's interesting to know that it *can* be done.