# How to make a nested class in PHP?

Tags: php

I'm new at PHP developing and I'm completely lost about how PHP handles classes and inheritance. As I've read, there are no nested classes in PHP. I'm coming from C#, and I'd like to reproduce the following structure:

```
private class GameScore {
        public TeamData[] teams =  new TeamData[2];                      
        public Boolean alert { get; set; }
        public String date { get; set; }
        public String time { get; set; }
        public class TeamData {                
            public String name { get; set; }
            public String score { get; set; }
        }
    }
```

Every GameScore should have the name of the teams who played the match and the score they got in the given match. I'd like to be able to store this data in the following way, to list several scores of multiple matches:

```
GameScore[] game = new GameScore[n];

game[0].alert = true;
game[0].date = "Oct. 17";
game[0].time = "15:25 EST";
game[0].teams[0].name = "Toronto Raptors";
game[0].teams[0].score = "0";
game[0].teams[1].name = "New York Knicks";
game[0].teams[1].score = "0";

...
```

EDIT: I tried the following structure:

```
class TeamData{
    public $name;
    public $score;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->name = '';
        $this->score = '';
    }
}

class GameScore{
    public $alert;
    public $date;
    public $time;

    public $team1;
    public $team2;

    function __construct(){
        $this->alert = false;
        $this->date = '';
        $this->time = '';
        $this->team1 = new TeamData();
        $this->team2 = new TeamData();
    }
}
```

Whereas this replicates the same structure written in C#, it doesn't generates any dependency between `GameScore` and `TeamData` (for example I need to instantiate `GameScore.TeamData` if I want to access this data type on C#, which is not the case on PHP using the above code)

What's the correct way to achieve this?

Comment: Why not extend the GameScore class? http://php.net/manual/en/keyword.extends.php

Comment: class GameScore
{
    public $teams;
    public $alert;
    public $date;
    public $time;
}

class TeamData
{
    public $name;
    public $score;
}

Comment: @Maximus2012 maybe I'm doing something wrong, I'll update my question with some code I tried

Comment: There will not be a separate TeamData object and obviously name and score will be elements of the GameScore object that you create. That is how extending a class works. If you need something from TeamData class only and not from GameScore class, then maybe you should just create an object of the TeamData class.

Comment: If you could update your question to indicate what exactly are you looking for and what should be the desired output then that would be helpful.

Comment: @Maximus2012 I updated my question with the expected result, passing from a highly typed language to all this freedom is confusing my head a bit

Comment: Now that you talk about dependencies, how do you want to mange them? You can't create and use them like you do in C#. Instead use a getter/setter or inject it as constructor args: __(TeamData $team1, TeamData $team2). Or use a DI container, there are many ways.

Comment: @burzum Initially I wanted to replicate the structure, which I made after reading the comments and answers given, I'd just want to know if there's a method to keep the dependency between them, aka not being able to instantiate a ``TeamData``object by itself. Can you please elaborate what's a DI container? I'm very new to PHP and I'm not familiar with the concept

Answer (score 2):

Familiarize Yourself with `traits` in `php`:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php

Comment: so with these traits you could implement the component pattern for videogames?

Comment: can you please elaborate more? I tried to use traits, but I found this exact issue in the process: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582747/how-to-make-a-variable-private-to-a-trait

Answer (score 0):

Php does not support nested classes
If TeamData does not need access to members of GameScore, you can write them as two separate classes, which seems to be the case.
And php has no built in get/set keywords, so getters and setters needs to be written manually.

Comment: about that I read about the magic methods, but I also read using those or any getter and setter is not a good practice for php, is that wrong? Besides, every game score needs the name of the teams who played and the scores which those teams got in that match, that's why they were related as an inner class