# PHP: Traits in Classes & other traits conflicting

Tags: php, traits

I have a problem with PHP traits.
I want to use a trait in a class and in a trait that is used in the class.

Example:

```
trait Loggable {
  protected function log(msg) { 
    echo msg; 
  }
}

trait SomeOtherTrait {
  use Loggable;
}

class MyClass {
  use SomeOtherTrait, Loggable;
}
```

But this results in a collision because Loggable is used twice in the class (once in the class, once through the other trait), but I don't understand the problem because encapsulating functionality is what traits are all about, right?
So I just want to use the log method everywhere I include the Loggable trait...

**So the question is: Why do I have a collision? Both (the trait and the class) point to the same Trait and the method, so it shouldn't be a conflict.**

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to use a trait several times in a class?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13582061/how-to-use-a-trait-several-times-in-a-class)

Comment: Unfortunately this solution isn't working. Changing SomeOtherTrait to `use Loggable { log as traitLog; }` and then `$this->traitLog(...)` gives the same error

Comment: A trait is not a substitute for multiple inheritance. It's only a substitute for copy-paste. In this case you pasted the same trait twice so all methods appear twice. The solution is fairly simple, just don't include `Loggable` in the top-level.

Comment: You don't have to use Loggable in MyClass because SomeOtherTrait already using Loggable trait so you have use log() function.

Answer (score 3):

Using a trait **copies** all its methods and properties to a class. It is not the same as extending. So actually you're trying to copy the same `log` method twice to `MyClass`.

If you really need/want to use both traits, you need to resolve this conflict as described in [the manual](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.traits.php#language.oop5.traits.conflict). For example:

```
class MyClass {
  use SomeOtherTrait, Loggable {
    SomeOtherTrait::log insteadof Loggable;
  }
}
```

Or:

```
class MyClass {
  use SomeOtherTrait, Loggable {
    Loggable::log as originalLog;
    SomeOtherTrait::log as overriddenLog;
  }

  public function test() {
    $this->originalLog('Logged with Loggable');
    $this->overriddenLog('Logged with SomeOtherTrait');
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

SomeOtherTrait uses the trait Loggable therefore you have access to all protected and public members of Loggable and the same applies to all classes which use the SomeOtherTrait. Here you have access to all public and protected members of Loggable and SomeOtherTrait.

```
trait Loggable {
   protected function log($msg) { 
      echo $msg; 
   }
}

trait SomeOtherTrait {
   use Loggable;
}

class MyClass {
   use SomeOtherTrait;

   public function test() 
   { 
       $this->log("test");
   }
}

$myClass = new MyClass();

$myClass->test();
```